# save each picture individually to individual jpg file (export image)

Tags: export, image

This piece of code returns 10 pictures all at once as output. However, I would like to save each mandala picture file separately. So design one will have **picture1.jpg**, design two will have **picture2.jpg** and design three will have **picture3.jpg** saved.

```
n = 10;
data = Multicolumn@
  MapThread[
   If[#1, MakeMandala[MakeSeedSegment[10, #2, #3], #2], 
     MakeMandala[
      MakeSymmetric[MakeSeedSegment[10, #2, #3, #4, False]], 
      2 #2]] &, {RandomChoice[{False, True}, n], 
    RandomChoice[{\[Pi]/7, \[Pi]/8, \[Pi]/6}, n], 
    RandomInteger[{8, 14}, n], 
    RandomChoice[{Line, Polygon, BezierCurve, 
      FilledCurve[BezierCurve[#]] &}, n]}]
Export["Picture1.jpg", %]
```

However, this code only save ALL desings to one jpg file. How can I fix this issue.

Thank you

Comment: The `Multicolumn[]` should be removed first. After that: `MapIndexed[Export["picture" <> Apply[IntegerString, #2] <> ".jpg", #] &, data]`

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you for your help. it worked.

Comment: Some tips: in Mathematica, "everything is an expression". The implication is that it is given that the plots can be stored in a list. They don't just exist in a notebook window, or as pixels on the screen. They're actual Mathematica expressions.  Once you know that, all you need is to loop through the list (or rather use `Map`/`Scan` or better: `MapIndexed`) and `Export` each element.